# want to add data in todo array how can i do this in firebase v9

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I created a collection "user", nd then created doc as a current logged in user ui (you can see in screenshot). Now I want to add todo in that `todo[]` array. How can i do this using latest version of firebase v9?

I tried, but getting some error. Please check `AddTodo()` method below.

[image]

```
 async register() {
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, this.email, this.password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
          const currentUserUid = userCredential.user.uid;  
          return setDoc(doc(db, "users", currentUserUid), {
            // add any additional user data here
            name: "fullName",
            email: "email",
            todo: [],
          });
        })
        .then(() => {
          // User registration and document creation successful
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.message);
        });
    },
```

```
async addTodo(){
if (this.newTodo != "" && this.newTask != "") {
        const currentUser = auth.currentUser;
        const currentUserUid = currentUser.uid;
        await addDoc(collection(db, currentUserUid), [
          {
            title: this.newTodo,
            task: this.newTask,
          },
        ]);
      }
}
```

Comment: "but getting some error." Please edit your question to include the exact error message tht you get and its stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Your second code snippet tries to **add** a new document to a **collection** named after the user's UID. That does not match the screenshot you have, which shows a **document** named after the UID in a **collection** names `users`.

To **update** the latter document, adding a task to the `tasks` array field:

```
async addTodo(){
  if (this.newTodo != "" && this.newTask != "") {
    const currentUser = auth.currentUser;
    const currentUserUid = currentUser.uid;
    await updateDoc(doc(db, 'users', currentUserUid), {
      tasks: arrayUnion([
        title: this.newTodo,
        task: this.newTask,
      ]},
    ]);
  }
}
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [adding and removing elements on an array field](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-9_12).